# Using \sqrt in the denominator of the \frac command

Tags: fractions

Below is the following code that I am trying to use in math mode.  When I do this it distorts the sqrt line and blends into the fraction line.

```
z=$\frac{ Estimate_{t} - Estimate_{t-1}} \sqrt{Var_{t} + Var_{t-1}}$
```

I don't know if it is a spacing issue with the `\frac` command or if I am missing a `{` some place.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is given already but that input must have generated an error message, something like `! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> } l.20 ...frac{ Estimate_{t} - Estimate_{t-1}} \sqrt` If you get an error message from tex any output you get is essentially arbitrary accidental recovery, so don't look at the spacing before fixing the error.

Answer (score 3):

The `\frac{}{}` command uses two pairs of braces:

```
$z=\frac{Estimate_{t} - Estimate_{t-1}}{\sqrt{Var_{t} + Var_{t-1}}}$
```

Please read some basic material such as the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX).